# Xamarin iOS SafeAreaInsets, where I should recalculate size of my controls?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need to use SafeAreaInsets in Xamarin iOS app. I've overrided OnAppearing() method and write some code for recalculating controls size like that:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
  StatusBar.Padding = /* ... */;
  base.OnAppearing();
}
```

This code works correctly, but seems it works after page already displayed, so I see for a second my page without sizes updating. But in documentation I see that OnAppearing() method should be executed before page Page become visible.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong. I've seen bugs in XForms related to changes made in OnAppearing not "taking affect" immediately. I would put those changes into page's constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`. And if you use a `BindingContext`, before `BindingContext = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it in XAML on top of the page and not in `OnAppearing`

```
<ContentPage ...
         xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         Title="Safe Area"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout

Comment: Thank you. But I need my specific calculations, not those which implemented in ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"